What to do with the coins offered to Kubera?
It is customary to offer Kubera some coins during the Puja.
I wonder, if the food offers become Prasna who consume the devotees, what become the coins and the precious offered to Kubera?
What does tradition provide?
Are they preserved to offer them in other Puja to the same Kubera?
Do they keep in a place and are no longer used in any case?
Or can they be spent?
Thanks
